# Как задать интервал между спавном объектов и ограничение в их количестве?

Tags: c#, unity3d

есть вот такой код

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class Spawner: MonoBehaviour {
  public Transform spawnPoint;
  public GameObject mob1;
  public GameObject mob2;
  public GameObject mob3;
  private int number;
  void Update() {
    if ((Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))) number=Random.Range(1, 4);
    if (number==1) Instantiate(mob1, spawnPoint.position, Quaternion.identity);
    if (number==2) Instantiate(mob2, spawnPoint.position, Quaternion.identity);
    if (number==3) Instantiate(mob3, spawnPoint.position, Quaternion.identity);
  }
}
```

Нужно сделать интервал между спавном,допустим 5 секунд и сделать ограниченное количество заспавненных обьектов, допустим 50. Поможете?

Comment: Начните решать задачу. Если не будет получаться, выкладывайте нерабочий код и конкретный вопрос, что именно не получается, тогда поможем разобраться. Решать задачи с нуля за автора здесь не принято.

Comment: все простые туторы давно есть на ютубе

Comment: Корутина (либо `time += Time.deltaTime` Update) и условие